# Trying to get property of non-objecte laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i have data and i print with dd($trending);

[image: result looks like:]

how to print in blade with foreach the name hashtag, i has try with

```
@foreach($trending[0] as $t )
        {!! $t->trends->name !!}
@endforeach
```

but result Trying to get property of non-object
can anyone solve this?

Comment: `$t` is already `$trending[0]->trends[x]` then just do `$t->name`

Comment: You could always `{{ dd($t) }}` in your `foreach` and see what `$t` looks like

Comment: thanks @HtmHell cheers!!

Comment: thanks @kerbholz cheeers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you everyone i found the aswer:

```
@foreach($trending[0]->trends as $t )
        {!! $t->name !!}
@endforeach
```

Comment: but in this case you will loop through first one only

Comment: yes @ali that is what i want, i want loop only name hashtag

Answer (score 0):

if you want to loop through each trending you can do the following:

```
  @foreach($trending as $trend )
     @foreach($trend as $t )
         {!! $t->name or 'no name available' !!}
     @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

Comment: @Ade have you pass this variable in view()?

Comment: @sandy yes i do